# How to create initial_data Json fixture for many-to-many relation?

Tags: database, django, json, django-models, many-to-many

I am creating an initializing file for for my django project database. I am doing this using a file called `initial_data.json` which i have created. For example the following code (when `syncdb` is run) creates in the model `Word` a new row where `name="apple"`:

`[ { "model": "sites.word", "pk": 1, "fields": { "name": "apple" } } ]`

I have managed to this so far for several models, the problem is with models that have a many-to-many field. I've looked around for the correct way to do this and have come up empty.

So, for example, if a `Model` mood has many `Interests` how would I write in the Json file that mood-1's interests are interest-1, interest-2 and interest-3.

What is the proper way to write in Json a models many-to-many relation?

EDIT:

@pastylegs solution was correct, I was just having trouble because the numbering of my interests was off in the Json file so it couldn't match them with there moods.

Comment: To help debugging you could try creating a many2many relationship and use ´manage.py dumpdata` to see what it looks like in json.

Comment: I've tried that, dumping and then syncing the table but it doesnt create the table correctly and the admin display crashes...

Comment: I'm going with "There's something wrong with your setup". The answers you're getting *are* the solutions; it's just that, for whatever reason, they aren't working for you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the manytomany field of your model can be written like a simple list:

```
 [
    { 
        "model": "sites.word", 
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": { 
            "name": "apple",
            "my_m2m_field_name": [1,2,3],
        }
     }
]
```

where 1, 2, 3 are the primary keys for the relations

Comment: It doesn't tell me anything is wrong but yet it still doesn't work... the wanted interests are not actually selected in the database

Comment: are the interests loaded in before the moods in the fixture?

Comment: They are before the moods in the Json file, as long as it is run top down then it adds the interests before the moods...

Comment: I'm not sure. This is definitely the way to load the fixtures, so the problem might be elsewhere

Comment: @pastylegs this seems to only work for lists containing 1 pk.

Comment: I noticed I put a comma after the last PK in the list in the example above, so I've taken it out. Maybe try with out that and see if Django is just being very particular with the formatting. After that I really don't know. This method works for me and I've been able to load m2m relationships. Have you tried doing this with another test project just to see if you can get it working?

Comment: I've accepted this answer since everyone agrees that it should work, it only works a little for me, I have a feeling though that it's a problem by me...

Comment: what was the problem in the end?

Comment: I wrote the problem in the end of my question, my interests pk's were numbered wrong...

Answer (score 5):

what I like to do is use the [dumpdata command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-dumpdata). I fire up a test site, use the admin form or the app itself to add just the data that I want to use in my fixture, then I run

```
./manage.py dumpdata appname > appname/fixtures/initial_data.json
```

You can dump all the apps together if you leave out appname but I like to do it separately for each model.

If you're using 1.3 (I'm not yet) then you can use `--exclude` to not dump some parts. I've aslo seen there is a `--indent` option to make the output pretty (just found that now while answering your question).

It's one of those things that's easy to miss in the documentation. ;-)

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: because it's easier to add the data through the admin interface and then see how it gets dumped out to use it as an example.